# UIScrollView redrawing content while scrolling?

Tags: iphone, uiview, scroll, uiscrollview, drawrect

I know there is a property or method that makes the scrollview/uiview call drawRect: method while is scrolling. By default is disabled because of performance reasons but I need to enable it. 
I cannot remember the name of the method hence I cannot look for it, anyone who knows what I am looking for?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'ld suggest to use the scrollViewDidScroll:-method and then redraw the view.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [someView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: I am afraid I cannot use this approach because actually I rendering only currently visible lines of text, so using this delegate method will show nothing until the the scroller completely stopped.

Comment: uh, this method is called at every change (even when the user is still dragging). So when the user drags 100px, this method is called 100 times (excluding the momentum).