# iOs: UIImageView setImage not working while scrolling

Tags: iphone, image, ipad, scroll, while-loop

I have an UITableView which has UIViews inside each cell (actually I'm using EasyTableView) and inside that view there are 3 UIImageViews changing images every 1/3 of a second.

The problem is, that the images change only while there's no scrolling happening.

I read some issues about this and I found people suggesting the use of NSRunLoop, but that's for NSURLConnection when loading external images, I'm using "UIImage imageNamed" and UIImageView's setImage. The other suggestion I read was to use NSInvocationOperation, but had no luck with that either.

```
    NSInvocationOperation *invocation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(changeProgress) object:nil];
[invocation start];
```

Maybe I'm doing it wrong, please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend found the solution, I had to create the timer without scheduling it, and add it to the NSRunLoop, so the code would be like this:

```
    _timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0/3.0 target:self selector:@selector(update:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:_timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

[UIScrollView redrawing content while scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465536/uiscrollview-redrawing-content-while-scrolling)

Comment: I tried setNeedsDisplay within the "changeProgress" method, but the problem is that changeProgress isn't called while scrolling, it just halts the timer I created. And adding UIScrollViewDelegate to it breaks EasyTableView :(